# Records don't load into edit page after update query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped on this one...  I'm using the following code to load a record into a form for editing.  The record loads fine into the fields etc.  I click submit and the record doesn't reload.  If I use edit_link.php?link_pk=50 in the url, the record doesn't load.  If I change the value to an unedited record it loads fine into the form, but if I edit that record, the same thing happens.  The data looks exactly the same in the database as it did before it was edited (ie I'm not changing anything before I submit):

```
$link_pk = $_GET['link_pk'];
$author_pk = $_GET['author_pk'];

$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
$url_for_link = $_POST['url'];
$alt = $_POST['alt'];
$credit = $_POST['credit'];
$sub_discipline_fk = $_POST['sub_discipline'];
$link_category_fk = $_POST['category'];
$icon = $_POST['icon'];

$query_link = "SELECT * FROM link, sub_discipline, link_category, link_icon WHERE link.sub_discipline_fk = sub_discipline.sub_discipline_pk AND link.link_category_fk = link_category.link_category_pk AND link.link_icon_fk = link_icon.link_icon_pk AND link.link_pk = '$link_pk'";
$result_link = mysql_query($query_link, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_link = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_link);


switch ($icon) {
    case '1':
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string("<a class='text' href='" . $url_for_link . "' target='_blank' alt='" . $alt . "' >" . $title . "</a>");
        break;
    case '2':
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string("<a class='video' href='" . $url_for_link . "' target='_blank' alt='" . $alt . "' >" . $title . "</a>");
        break;
    case '3':
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string("<a class='interactive' href='" . $url_for_link . "' target='_blank' alt='" . $alt . "' >" . $title . "</a>");
        break;
    case '4':
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string("<a class='microscope' href='" . $url_for_link . "' target='_blank' alt='" . $alt . "' >" . $title . "</a>");
        break;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        $query = "UPDATE link SET link_title = '$title', url = '$url', link = '$link', alt = '$alt', credit = '$credit', sub_discipline_fk = '$sub_discipline_fk', updated = NOW(), updated_by = '$author_pk', link_category_fk = '$link_category_fk', link_icon_fk = '$link_icon_fk' WHERE link_pk = '$link_pk'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                if($result){
                    $query_link = "SELECT * FROM link, sub_discipline, link_category, link_icon WHERE link.sub_discipline_fk = sub_discipline.sub_discipline_pk AND link.link_category_fk = link_category.link_category_pk AND link.link_icon_fk = link_icon.link_icon_pk AND link.link_pk = '$link_pk'";
$result_link = mysql_query($query_link, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_link = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_link);
            $message = '- The link has been updated';
        }
}
```

Please do not remind me that the above is depricated, I'm aware of that.

Thanks

Comment: Hey; Your code is deprecated

Comment: That should be 'depricated' ;>

Comment: `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0`  --- http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  -- Spelling is correct :>

Comment: Really stumped on this...even if I delete all the data in the field for a record except for the primary key, the record won't load into the form after editing, but it will load a new record.  It's as if the rcord is being corrupted after editing, but nothing obvious...

Comment: Basic trouble shooting.. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and `if(!$query){  echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";  }    --- There are tools to help you trouble shoot this

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake...I changed a variable name and didntt change it in the query... link_icon_fk = '$link_icon_fk' should have been link_icon_fk = '$icon' - trying to work too fast...